# Three.js how to show/update Geometry Segments?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a simple `TRHEE.BoxGeometry` in a `THREE.Scene`. I want to show the outline of the Geometry Segments (not the Mesh).

I found an [example here](http://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#BoxGeometry) that does exactly that, but I can't reproduce.

Given [example](http://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#BoxGeometry) looks like image below.

**How do I show segments outlines and how would I update the geometry at runtime?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second mesh duplicate using geometry.clone.

```
material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);


var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color:0xFF0000,
  wireframe:true
});
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.clone(), material2);
scene.add(mesh2);
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nss1n5tv/

You can use wireframeLinewidth to specify the thickness of the line.

Comment: Great, this points me in the right direction. I am wondering however, in the ``animate`` loop, ``mesh.rotation`` and ``mesh2.rotation`` are hardcoded values. How would I make ``mesh2.rotation`` inherit ``mesh.rotation``? (same hold for position and scale).

Comment: A "Scene" is an object3d class type. Therefore any object3d, any mesh, can have meshes added to it as children. See this adjusted fiddle. It's a simple change which adds the second mesh to the first: http://jsfiddle.net/dqrr6qwq/     There are caveats to creating children, mostly in updating items through child iteration. Post new questions as you have them.

Comment: Solves my problem. Thanks a lot!